# sendmail DSN: User unknown error

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I am trying to send email using sendmail on ubuntu 14.04

I have installed `sendmail` package on the VM.

```
echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail muname@domain.com
```

when I checked /var/log/mail.log found

```
Oct 14 15:19:39 wn2-aerq01 sm-mta[47774]: u9EFJX6f047770: to=<myname@domain.com>, ctladdr=<sshuser@localhost.localdomain> (2017/2017), delay=00:00:06, xdelay=00:00:05, mailer=esmtp, pri=120349, relay=domain-com.mail...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.170], dsn=5.7.1, stat=User unknown
Oct 14 15:19:49 wn2-aerq01 sm-mta[47774]: u9EFJX6f047770: u9EFJn6f047774: DSN: User unknown
Oct 14 15:19:49 wn2-aerq01 sm-mta[47774]: u9EFJn6f047774: to=<sshuser@localhost.localdomain>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

I have these config files

/etc/mail/sendmail.conf : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/456578/05403714/

/etc/mail/sendmail.mc : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/456579/54109147/

/etc/mail/access : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/456588/55139147/

Anyone know whats wrong here ?

Comment: Looks like your trying to relay mail for the local server via outlook.com and thats whys its reporting unknown user. Do you have `smart_relay` enabled or something in your config?

Comment: config files added in my question

Comment: can you add `/etc/mail/access` as well please. I can't see anything from a very quick glance. What domain name is your local server using and what do you get if you telnet direct to your box on port 25. I'll try and have a look a bit later when I'm back from work.

Comment: /etc/mail/access added. This VM is running in Azure with domain xyz.cx.internal.cloudapp.net

Comment: Hmmm... Azure.... I'm not sure what they do with mail. does mail to *any* local user work when you send it to the fully qualified domain name from the same server? I think M$ might be hijacking the connections. I have no Azure experience but I do run many sendmail boxes.

Comment: It works on other Azure VM, so not sure if M$ blocking it.

Comment: might be worth double checking for any wildcarding of the domain or at least any differences between this not working setup and another working one